# Running javascript program in VsCode

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code

I watched a tutorial on how to run javascript programs in VScode. I installed Node.js, checked the version in Command Prompt which showed it was working and npm version also. I then headed to install the necessary extensions in VsCode which are the Javascript ES6 and code runner as instructed in the video, but when i run the code it brings this error below

'node' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

What do i need to do?

I tried to run a javascript code in VsCode after installing the Javascript ES6 and Code runner extensions

I was expecting the code to run as normal, since i had followed all instructions in the tutorial video

Comment: Have you tried closing VS Code, and re-open it.  The PATH environment inside VS code might not have updated..

Comment: Is it window os ?? which terminal you used??

Comment: Thank you keith, i closed VsCode and reopened it and it worked this time. The terminal ran the code. Thanks a bunch